# How To Sell Music From Google Play In Your Android App?

Tags: android, google-play

I have requirement from client to display google music of his album in android app from where he could sell it.

I searched on Google and come to know that there is no Official API available for this, any one suggest me any alternative way or solution to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A Google search for Google Play unofficial API brings up this Java-based Option:

https://github.com/jkiddo/gmusic.api

Comment: i come to know that there is no Official API, i know this man :)

Comment: Right... So you are looking for a way to do this without any api? Or you are looking for api suggestions?

Comment: @UMAR, I'd imagine you could play around with the store to get an idea of which URLs are called, in order to map out your own URL queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link directly to the Google Play store, the best way to do it is probably to figure out the web URL for the product you want to link to, and then call it as a VIEW intent.  For instance:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bwp56isr3gk7dcvakz3zvqr5kry"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If the device has the Google Play app installed it will intercept these URLs and give you the option to open them with the Google Play app.

Normally you would use market:// URLs to get directly to the Play Store app, but unfortunately it appears that you can only use those URLs for apps.

Comment: So it could be the alternative way to list down music album and if user wants to purchase it, he can do that from google play music app by clicking on it inside of your own app am i right?

Comment: The purchasing would happen in the Google Play app.  You would be making a 'BUY' button or a link in your own app that takes them there.  If you need to pull the artist/album data for display inside your app this won't really help.  It assumes you already know the artist/albums you want to sell.

Comment: No you did'nt understand, if i opened the url in the browser then it will do the rest process of buying itself, as google has not provided official API to important music content and i dont want to use un-official API, then browser is the only solution i see. Just a last question if the Google music app is not installed in the phone then what would happen? if a user wants to still purchase the music? Google will allow it or it will ask to install that app?

Comment: Normally these kinds of purchases are completed through the Google Play Store app which is installed on most Android devices.  The Google Music app just plays the music, it's not for buying.  When you try to view a URL to play.google.com in an Android intent it will offer to launch the Google Play Store app if you have it installed.  If it's not installed the URL would go to the browser.  Still, it's a good idea to wrap your calls to startActivity in a try/catch block in case there is no app at all which will handle the URL.